# PHP code to allow access for input of a specific number in a form

Tags: php, forms

Please, I need a php code that I can use to allow access to a particular page if only a particular number is entered in a form.

The number could be 1111. If a user enters 1111 in a simple form, it will be processed by a submit.php page that will check if the user submitted the correct number. If yes, the user will be redirected to a new page. Else, the user will be redirected to error page.

Please help me, because I am new to PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Andy: tutorial like questions are considered off-topic for SO, do read our [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guide and [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you run into a problems with your code, post it here and we can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to achieve you goal

In a file create a form and submit the form on another `check.php` file

```
<form method="post" action="check.php"> 
    Enter Code: <input name="code"   type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />      
</form>
```

In `check.php` file

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['code'])) ///check id form is posted and not empty value of code.
{
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    if($code == 1111) ### verify if code is equal to 1111.
    {
        header("Location: newpage.php"); ### Redirect to new page.
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: error.php"); ### Redirect to error page.
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.